# C++ data structure similar to std::map with multiple key levels

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, containers

I would like to have a data structure similar to `std::map` with multiple key levels. For example in this my_map :

```
(‘a’ , “a1”) ->  “value1”
(‘a’ , “a2”) ->  “value2”
(‘b’ , “b1”) ->  “value3”
(‘b’ , “b2”) ->  “value4”
```

The first level key values are chars: `['a' and 'b']` and the second key levels are `std::string` ("a1", etc) and the values are strings.

API requirements:

Adding elements using two key values.
Retrieve elements by the first key: `my_map.at_first_level('a')`, this should return a map like:

```
"a1" -> “value1”
"a2" -> “value2”
```

Is this "multi-level map" data structure implemented in any of the C++ libraries?

Comment: What about `map<char, map<string, string>>`?

Comment: Take a look at [Boost Multi-index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) .

Comment: @JesperJuhl I was looking at it right now. It is exactly what I want.

Comment: Seems pretty unclear if you need multi-index container or map of maps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest Boost MultiIndex with `composite_key` https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html

Here's a recent example I gave using it:

- [equal_range in boost::Multi_Indexed_Container Composite key with comparision operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576367/equal-range-in-boostmulti-indexed-container-composite-key-with-comparision-ope/50579142#50579142)

Answer (score 7):

Have you considered a map of maps ?

```
std::map<char, std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;
```

Comment: This will work, but if I have more than two levels, the syntax would be cumbersome. I was hoping that someone has implemented a multi-level map similar to Pandas multi-index in C++, where you can lookup values by level number and level key.

Comment: @motam79 If you have multiple levels maybe you are not mapping the problem correctly ? Are you sure you are using the correct data structure for the problem ?

Comment: @motam79 Could you give an example of the syntax you would prefer in your question?