# Boost:Multi-index: How to iterate over all results matching a non-unique ordered index?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a Boost multi-index container for storing `MyClass` members. It has a unique (first_field) and non-unique (second field) indices:

```
typedef multi_index_container<
MyClass,
indexed_by<
        ordered_unique<member<MyClass, std::string, MyClass.first_field>>,
        ordered_non_unique<member<MyClass &, std::string, MyClass.second_field>>>
> MyClass_Set;
```

If I search the container by the second index:

```
auto it = container.get<1>().find("second_field_value_to_be_searched);
```

I get a const iterator back. How do I iterate over ALL elements in the container that matches the above predicate?

Comment: `container.get<1>()` returns a container view ordered by index 1. `find` returns an iterator into *that* view. You advance it while the predicate holds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, use `equal_range` instead:

```
auto r = container.get<1>().equal_range("second_field_value_to_be_searched");
```

This yields a pair of iterators. You can iterate them as usual, or wrap them in an iterator range:

```
for (auto& record : boost::make_iterator_range(r)) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There was no way for me to figure this out from the documentation.

Comment: BTW, when I iterate through the results. they are not sorted by the first index. Is this expected?

Comment: Yes, that's expected. Anyways, `equal_range` is a [concept from STL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal_range), which is available on all ordered node-based standard library containers (e.g. [{multi}set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/equal_range), [{multi}map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range), obviously more useful on the non-unique variants. Unsurprisingly, the MulitIndex order indices copy that interface: [set operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html#set_operations)

Comment: If you want items to be ordered by composite key (so e.g. items returned by a query for the first part key are ordered by the second), look at [`composite_key`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html#composite_key) which is also described in the [tutorial section](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/key_extraction.html#composite_keys). You can also look at some of my examples, [e.g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50576367//50579142#50579142)